# An example of a non-compact operator which is equal to (norm) limit of compact operators

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

For a normed linear space $X$ and a Banach space $Y$, the set of all compact operator from $X$ to $Y$, which is denoted by $K(X,Y)$, is normed closed in $B(X,Y)$.

Is there a counterexample which shows that the completeness of $Y$ is necessary?
In other words, can be a non-compact operator is equal to (norm)limit of compact operators?

Comment: That depends on the exact definition of compactness. If your def. is that $\overline{T(M)}$ is compact for bounded sets $M \subset X$, then there probably is a counterexample. If your definition is that the image $T(M)$ of a bounded set $M$ is totally bounded (i.e. the closure **in the completion** is compact), then limits of compact operators will be compact. The same holds if your definition is in terms of sequences. If you want $T x_n$ to have a convergent subsequence, then there probably is a counterexample. In case that $T x_n$ is to have a **Cauchy** subsequence, limits will be compact.

Comment: @PhoemueX Your comment should be an answer, so that [this new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703532/showing-an-operator-is-not-compact) can be closed as a duplicate. Or should the link as duplicate be in the other direction?