# Showing an operator is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Im studying functional analysis and I don't know how to solve this exercise:

We define $T:c_0\rightarrow l^2$ as $T((x_j))=(x_j/j)$. Let $X=c_0$ and $Y=Im(T)$. Let $S\in L(X,Y)$ defined by $S(x)=T(x)$. Show that $S$ is not compact and that is the limit of a sequence of finite range operators.

I don't know how to show that $S$ is not compact and about the second question, in class I have seen that the limit of finite range operators is compact, but I don't know what hypothesis fail in this example.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the comment in  this post: [An example of a non-compact operator which is equal to (norm) limit of compact operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923347/an-example-of-a-non-compact-operator-which-is-equal-to-norm-limit-of-compact-o)

Comment: Is the image of $T$ closed in $\ell^2$?

Comment: It doesn't specify it

Comment: @Miguel_lopdur Sure it doesn't, but you know $T,$ so you can find out.

Comment: @AnneBauval oh sorry, I will try it, I suppose that will show the part of the contradiction, doesnt't it?

Comment: Show directly that $S$ is not compact in the sense of the **first** definition of the comment to the **post linked above**, i.e. that $\overline{S(B)}$ is not compact, and a corollary will be that the image of $T$ is not closed. @BrianMoehring's comment was just a hint to remind you the forgotten hypothesis in your "the limit of finite range operators is compact" (in the sense of that definition).