Space of compact operators $K(X,Y)$ for normed spaces $X, Y$
I have already read a similar question "Why is the set of compact operators closed in the space of all bounded operators between Banach spaces?" and I want to ask a similar question (so I am not really sure, of it is worth it, to make another question, or should I just write it as a comment on previous):
Is the set $K(X,Y)$ (compact operators from normed vector space $X$ to normed vector space $Y$) a closed subspace of $B(X,Y)$ (bounded operators) in the case that $Y$ is not Banach?
Compact operator is defined as operator from $X$ to $Y$, such that closure in $Y$ (not in completion of $Y$) of image of unit ball (in $X$) under the operator is compact, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces and operator is a linear mapping.
It follows immediately from the fact that every compact set of metric space is bounded, that compact operators are bounded.
I am reading "Banach space theory" by Canadian Mathematical Society and here it is the proposition 1.40: "Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces. Then $F(X,Y)$ is a linear subspace of $K(X,Y)$. The space $K(X,Y)$ is a closed subspace of $B(X,Y)$; hence if Y is a Banach space, then $K(X,Y)$ is also a Banach space."
So, they are saying, that Y need not to be Banach, but in the proof is only proved, that if $T_n \to T$, then $T$ (unit ball) is totally bounded but not that its closure is complete(which would be obvious if $Y$ was assumed to be Banach).
So I want also ask, if I misinterpreted something in the book and if I need to find another book for studying Banach spaces.

Any operator from $X$ to $Y$ can also be considered as  an operator from $X$ into the completion of $Y$. $T$ is compact if the every sequence in the image of the  unit  has a convergent subsequence. I don't think the closure of the image has to be contained in $Y$. This is my undersatnding. My be I am wrong.

kostya, what is your (or your book's) precise definition of $K(X,Y)$ for arbitrary normed spaces $X,Y$? Please don't answer in comment but edit your post. Alternatively, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923347 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703532.

I've edited your question to specify that you are talking about $K(X, Y)$ for normed spaces $X, Y$. The title appeared to me as if you were talking about, say, a Frechet space $Y$.

Here is a counterexample: Let $X = c_0$, $T$ be defined by,
$$T((a_n)_n) = (\frac{a_n}{n})_n$$
with $Y = \text{range}(T)$, equipped with the $\ell^2$-norm. Then $T$ is not compact. Indeed, the sequence $\{T(\sum_{k=1}^n e_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e_k}{k}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is contained in $T(B_X)$, where $B_X$ is the closed unit ball of $X$. But, it has no convergent subsequence, as it has a limit $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e_k}{k}$ in $\ell^2$, but this limit point is not in $Y = \text{range}(T)$.
However, $T$ is the norm limit of a sequence of finite rank operators $T_k: X \to Y$, defined by,
$$T_k((a_n)_n) = (\frac{a_1}{1}, \frac{a_2}{2}, \cdots, \frac{a_k}{k}, 0, 0, \cdots)$$
Finite rank operators are always compact, so this yields a counterexample.

Note that I’m strictly working with the OP’s definition of compact operators. It is not the best way to define compact operators when the codomain is not Banach, in my opinion, and my answer can be understood as one of the deficiencies of this definition.

I was simultaneoulsy editing essentially the same answer in one of the two the posts linked in my prior comment 2 hours ago, and from which our common counterexample is borrowed. Better answer an original post than a duplicate, and close the latter as such.
